# Postgres: One-to-many relationship with WHERE, ORDER BY and LIMIT not scalable?

Tags: index, execution-plan, postgresql-performance, index-tuning, scalability

I'm currently using Postgres 12.
A few years ago, I set up the following model: a `lot` table with a one-to-many relationship to a `line` table. My idea was to mutualize data that are common for multiple rows of the `line` table, into the `lot` table.
The `lot` table contains metadata stored as in a JSONB column, it felt right at the time not to duplicate the data, since a lot could contain 1 to 10 lines.

Users can ask for lines through an API in a paginated manner, using seek pagination on a `sort_index` column in the `line` table. Users can also filter on multiple columns.
I'm currently having issues to scale. I have ~40M rows in the line table for ~8M rows in the lot table.

Here is a simplified view of the model:

```
\d+ public.lot
                                                   Table "public.lot"
     Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id              | uuid                     |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 metadata        | jsonb                    |           | not null |         | extended |              |
 discriminant_id | bigint                   |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 date_created    | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 last_updated    | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "lot_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_lot_discriminant_id" btree (discriminant_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_lot_discriminant" FOREIGN KEY (discriminant_id) REFERENCES public.discriminant(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "public.line" CONSTRAINT "fk_line_lot" FOREIGN KEY (lot_id) REFERENCES public.lot(id)
Access method: heap
Options: autovacuum_enabled=true, toast.autovacuum_enabled=true
```

```
\d+ public.line
                                       Table "public.line"
   Column   |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | uuid   |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 type       | text   |           | not null |         | extended |              |
 sort_index | bigint |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 lot_id     | uuid   |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "line_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_line_lot" btree (lot_id)
    "idx_line_sort_index" btree (sort_index)
    "idx_line_type" btree (type)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_line_lot" FOREIGN KEY (lot_id) REFERENCES public.lot(id)
Access method: heap
```

and a simplified query that I've problem with:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM public.lot lot
         JOIN public.line line ON lot.id = line.lot_id
WHERE lot.discriminant_id = $discriminant_id
ORDER BY line.sort_index DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

From what I understand of how the planer should behave, it should choose between:

- Plan 1: Scanning the index `idx_line_sort_index` to retrieve lines sorted correctly, then filter rows on the condition `discriminant_id = $discriminant_id`
- Plan 2: Scanning the index `idx_lot_discriminant_id` to filter on lots with a discriminant_id = $discriminant_id, then sort the matching lines

From what I know, the planner should choose between the two plans based on statistics:

- Plan 1 will be chosen for slightly selective `$discriminant_id` values, since it's better to sort first, then filter.
- Plan 2 will be chosen for highly selective `$discriminant_id` values, since it's better to filter, then sort.

However, I got always the same plan:
For $discriminant_id=2003, a filter not selective matching ~30% of the total lot table:

```
                                                                           QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1.00..19.96 rows=10 width=923) (actual time=189.045..189.397 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.00..25037693.73 rows=13206387 width=923) (actual time=189.042..189.393 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_line_sort_index on line  (cost=0.56..2881081.84 rows=40287948 width=56) (actual time=0.139..8.513 rows=2500 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using lot_pkey on lot  (cost=0.43..0.55 rows=1 width=859) (actual time=0.072..0.072 rows=0 loops=2500)
               Index Cond: (id = line.lot_id)
               Filter: (discriminant_id = 2003)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 8.149 ms
 Execution Time: 189.787 ms
(9 rows)
```

For $discriminant_id=2173, a filter very selective matching only a few rows in the lot table, I have the same plan, and very bad performances:

```
                                                                                      QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1001.02..31878.16 rows=10 width=923) (actual time=178184.893..178185.317 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1001.02..11879434.51 rows=3847 width=923) (actual time=178184.890..178185.312 rows=10 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.00..11877990.44 rows=1603 width=923) (actual time=73048.846..73050.343 rows=7 loops=3)
               ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using idx_line_sort_index on line  (cost=0.56..2646068.81 rows=16786645 width=56) (actual time=0.121..26016.348 rows=13428898 loops=3)
               ->  Index Scan using lot_pkey on lot  (cost=0.43..0.55 rows=1 width=859) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=40286694)
                     Index Cond: (id = line.lot_id)
                     Filter: (discriminant_id = 2173)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 0.904 ms
 Execution Time: 178185.392 ms
(12 rows)
```

At first, I thought it was a statistic problem, so I check the pg_stats table:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_stats
WHERE tablename = 'lot' AND attname = 'discriminant_id';
```

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
schemaname             | pub
tablename              | lot
attname                | discriminant_id
inherited              | f
null_frac              | 0
avg_width              | 8
n_distinct             | 204
most_common_vals       | {2003,2349,2063,2199,2256,2002,2104,2215,2060,2042,2113,2004,2066,2101,2006,2049,2058,2156,2177,2007,2052,2043,2046,2064,2100,2050,2367,2165,2055,2164,2213,2216,2260,2200,2154,2190,2191,2158,2044,2001,2179,2201,2189,2105,2174,2187,2205,2161,2162,2309,2196,2108,2183,2312,2188,2194,2182,2197,2198,2008,2263,2181,2267,2048,2195,2062,2379,2180,2059,2112,2163,2171,2271,2106,2057,2206,2348,2381,2061,2120,2212,2005,2053,2259,2274,2115,2313,2121,2193,2251,2264,2099,2184,2262,2398,2419,2207,2409,2413,2422}
most_common_freqs      | {0.3278,0.1092,0.029466666,0.029466666,0.0294,0.0278,0.026333334,0.026333334,0.0224,0.020533333,0.0203,0.0194,0.018033333,0.0156,0.014733333,0.010433333,0.0093,0.0091,0.0091,0.008466667,0.0079666665,0.0073,0.0069333334,0.0068,0.0067,0.0064333333,0.0064333333,0.006366667,0.0062666666,0.005866667,0.0058,0.005433333,0.0047,0.0046666665,0.0046,0.0042333333,0.0042333333,0.0040666666,0.0039333333,0.0039,0.0037333334,0.0037,0.0032666668,0.0032,0.0031666667,0.0028,0.0028,0.0027,0.0026666666,0.0026333334,0.0024,0.0023333333,0.0022666666,0.0022666666,0.0021666666,0.0021,0.0020333333,0.0019666667,0.0019666667,0.0019,0.0019,0.0018,0.0018,0.0017,0.0017,0.0016,0.0016,0.0015333333,0.0014666667,0.0014333334,0.0014,0.0013666666,0.0013333333,0.0013,0.0012666667,0.0012666667,0.0012333334,0.0012,0.0010333334,0.00093333336,0.00093333336,0.0009,0.0009,0.00086666667,0.0008,0.00073333335,0.00073333335,0.0007,0.0007,0.0007,0.0007,0.0006,0.0006,0.00056666665,0.00053333334,0.0005,0.00046666668,0.00046666668,0.00046666668,0.00043333333}
histogram_bounds       | {2041,2047,2047,2054,2056,2056,2065,2065,2103,2103,2109,2109,2109,2114,2117,2119,2160,2160,2160,2168,2170,2175,2178,2178,2202,2202,2202,2203,2204,2211,2211,2250,2250,2252,2252,2253,2254,2254,2254,2255,2258,2258,2266,2266,2266,2268,2268,2269,2272,2273,2273,2359,2362,2362,2363,2366,2370,2370,2377,2378,2380,2383,2390,2390,2392,2397,2400,2402,2405,2426}
correlation            | 0.17503545
most_common_elems      |
most_common_elem_freqs |
elem_count_histogram   |
```

Everything looks fine to me, but I could not understand the plan chosen by the planer. So I tried to bump stats sampling for the column `discriminant_id`:

```
ALTER TABLE public.lot ALTER COLUMN discriminant_id SET STATISTICS 500;
ANALYZE public.lot;
```

I got more sampling in the pg_stats table:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
schemaname             | pub
tablename              | lot
attname                | discriminant_id
inherited              | f
null_frac              | 0
avg_width              | 8
n_distinct             | 204
most_common_vals       | {2003,2349,2256,2002,2199,2063,2104,2215,2060,2042,2113,2004,2066,2101,2006,2049,2058,2177,2007,2156,2052,2046,2064,2043,2050,2055,2100,2213,2367,2260,2165,2191,2154,2200,2164,2216,2190,2158,2179,2044,2001,2105,2205,2201,2189,2174,2161,2162,2187,2188,2196,2267,2309,2183,2194,2312,2263,2198,2181,2182,2163,2197,2379,2108,2057,2195,2106,2381,2062,2048,2059,2112,2348,2271,2180,2274,2008,2120,2005,2171,2061,2212,2206,2259,2313,2053,2121,2115,2099,2054,2184,2193,2251,2419,2264,2258,2422,2262,2254,2160,2398,2397,2409,2103,2065,2250,2252,2413,2362,2366,2268,2056,2380,2202,2109,2170,2204,2370,2207,2047,2114,2266,2211,2178,2390,2116,2118,2377,2272,2363,2217,2175,2176,2255,2400,2408,2378,2394,2405,2373,2384,2402,2155,2392,2117,2385,2275}
most_common_freqs      | {0.32298,0.108333334,0.029793333,0.029746667,0.0289,0.02848,0.02712,0.02536,0.02328,0.020573333,0.02038,0.019706666,0.018566666,0.01624,0.015613333,0.011046667,0.00908,0.009073333,0.008833333,0.008486667,0.007833334,0.0072333333,0.00708,0.00702,0.006853333,0.006726667,0.0063866666,0.0062066666,0.0061533335,0.0057666665,0.00576,0.004833333,0.0047533335,0.0047533335,0.0046066665,0.004526667,0.0042933333,0.00394,0.0038466668,0.0038066667,0.00356,0.0034933332,0.00344,0.00336,0.0031733334,0.00304,0.00276,0.00276,0.00276,0.0026333334,0.0025066666,0.0024533332,0.0022866668,0.00224,0.0021333334,0.0020933333,0.0020333333,0.0019933332,0.0019066667,0.00188,0.0018666667,0.0018133334,0.00178,0.0017533334,0.0017266667,0.0016066667,0.00158,0.0015333333,0.0015266667,0.0014866666,0.0014866666,0.0014333334,0.0013333333,0.00132,0.00124,0.00124,0.0011133334,0.0010666667,0.0010533333,0.0010533333,0.00098,0.00098,0.0009733333,0.00088,0.00086,0.00082666666,0.00077333336,0.00076666666,0.0007533333,0.0006466667,0.00064,0.00060666667,0.00056666665,0.00052666664,0.00047333332,0.00046666668,0.00045333334,0.00044,0.00041333333,0.0004,0.0004,0.00038666668,0.00038666668,0.00038,0.00033333333,0.00031333332,0.00031333332,0.00031333332,0.0003,0.0003,0.00029333335,0.00028666668,0.00028,0.00027333334,0.00025333333,0.00025333333,0.00025333333,0.00024,0.00023333334,0.00022,0.00022,0.00022,0.00020666666,0.0002,0.0002,0.00018666667,0.00018666667,0.00018,0.00017333333,0.00017333333,0.00015333333,0.00013333333,0.00012666667,0.00012666667,0.00012,0.000113333335,0.00010666667,0.00010666667,0.00010666667,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,9.3333336e-05,9.3333336e-05,8.666667e-05,8.666667e-05,8e-05}
histogram_bounds       | {2041,2051,2051,2119,2157,2167,2168,2168,2169,2192,2208,2253,2253,2269,2270,2273,2273,2310,2311,2314,2357,2358,2359,2359,2361,2361,2361,2364,2365,2369,2369,2371,2383,2395,2395,2399,2401,2401,2407,2415,2418,2426,2432,2432}
correlation            | 0.17252338
most_common_elems      |
most_common_elem_freqs |
elem_count_histogram   |
```

Still, the value `2173` is still not in the `common_vals` array. At this point, I wouldn't be surprised to see the same execution plan.

However, for $discriminant_id=2173, and after the stats inflation, my query planned changed for the best:

```
                                                                     QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=26989.83..26989.86 rows=10 width=923) (actual time=21.925..21.930 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=26989.83..26992.10 rows=908 width=923) (actual time=21.920..21.922 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: line.sort_index DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 65kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.00..26970.21 rows=908 width=923) (actual time=13.881..21.228 rows=20 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using idx_lot_discriminant_id on lot  (cost=0.43..718.59 rows=183 width=859) (actual time=9.429..9.688 rows=4 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (discriminant_id = 2173)
               ->  Index Scan using idx_line_lot on line  (cost=0.56..143.10 rows=35 width=56) (actual time=2.159..2.865 rows=5 loops=4)
                     Index Cond: (lot_id = lot.id)
 Planning Time: 3.137 ms
 Execution Time: 22.082 ms
(11 rows)
```

For $discriminant_id=2003, after the stats inflation, the planer still choose to pass through the `idx_line_sort_index` (which is indeed the most accurate plan):

```
                                                                           QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1.00..20.24 rows=10 width=923) (actual time=20.670..20.711 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.00..25037693.73 rows=13012200 width=923) (actual time=20.665..20.704 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_line_sort_index on line  (cost=0.56..2881081.84 rows=40287948 width=56) (actual time=0.039..3.832 rows=2500 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using lot_pkey on lot  (cost=0.43..0.55 rows=1 width=859) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=2500)
               Index Cond: (id = line.lot_id)
               Filter: (discriminant_id = 2003)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 0.888 ms
 Execution Time: 20.807 ms
(9 rows)
```

I don't why, but it seems that altering the stats sampling helps the planer to choose the plans I was waiting for, according to the selectivity of the `discriminant_id` column. Even if the `pg_stats` did not really change for the specific values 2003, and 2173.

I ran some tests, and it seems my problems did not end here:
For $discriminant_id=2191, matching ~0.5% of the `lot` table, before the stat inflation:

```
                                                                               QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1.00..1060.32 rows=10 width=921) (actual time=7011.736..42354.274 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.00..25037693.73 rows=236355 width=921) (actual time=7011.720..42354.255 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_line_sort_index on line  (cost=0.56..2881081.84 rows=40287948 width=56) (actual time=0.273..16201.866 rows=10036046 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using lot_pkey on lot  (cost=0.43..0.55 rows=1 width=857) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=10036046)
               Index Cond: (id = line.lot_id)
               Filter: (discriminant_id = 2191)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 12.324 ms
 Execution Time: 42354.448 ms
(9 rows)
```

After the stats inflation:

```
                                                                               QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1.00..1392.35 rows=10 width=924) (actual time=5870.174..40331.055 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.00..25037693.73 rows=179952 width=924) (actual time=5870.166..40331.044 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_line_sort_index on line  (cost=0.56..2881081.84 rows=40287948 width=56) (actual time=0.583..15596.227 rows=10036046 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using lot_pkey on lot  (cost=0.43..0.55 rows=1 width=860) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=10036046)
               Index Cond: (id = line.lot_id)
               Filter: (discriminant_id = 2191)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 3.152 ms
 Execution Time: 40331.218 ms
(9 rows)
```

The plans are slightly different, but the idea is the same: the query seems too slow to me.
Bumping the stats to the maximum (10000) does not solve this issue, the query is still slow.

From what I guess, the planer thinks it will be faster to scan the sort_index then filter, because it thinks that the values to return will be very "contiguous" on the index, and underestimates the filter to do on the discriminant.

```
SELECT line.sort_index FROM public.line line
JOIN public.lot lot ON line.lot_id = lot.id
WHERE lot.discriminant_id = 2191
ORDER BY line.sort_index DESC
LIMIT 10;
sort_index
------------
39224084
39224083
39224082
39224081
39223063
30288652 <---- 8934411 lines between this one and the previous, due to the filtering.
30288651
30288650
30288649
30288609
(10 rows)
```

We indeed see that there is a huge gap between the same query depending on the number of rows returned:
In the case of limiting the rows to 5, the scanning of the `idx_line_sort_index` estimates 1M rows to scan

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT * FROM public.line line
JOIN public.lot lot ON line.lot_id = lot.id
WHERE lot.discriminant_id = 2191
ORDER BY line.sort_index DESC
LIMIT 5;
                                                                              QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1.00..696.67 rows=5 width=924) (actual time=3506.308..3512.160 rows=5 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.00..25037693.73 rows=179952 width=924) (actual time=3506.306..3512.158 rows=5 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_line_sort_index on line  (cost=0.56..2881081.84 rows=40287948 width=56) (actual time=0.159..1212.901 rows=1012824 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using lot_pkey on lot  (cost=0.43..0.55 rows=1 width=860) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1012824)
               Index Cond: (id = line.lot_id)
               Filter: (discriminant_id = 2191)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 1.565 ms
 Execution Time: 3512.199 ms
(9 rows)
```

In the case of limiting the rows to 6, the scanning of the `idx_line_sort_index` estimates 10M (x10) rows to scan

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT * FROM public.line line
JOIN public.lot lot ON line.lot_id = lot.id
WHERE lot.discriminant_id = 2191
ORDER BY line.sort_index DESC
LIMIT 6;
                                                                               QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1.00..835.81 rows=6 width=924) (actual time=3539.010..38743.824 rows=6 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.00..25037693.73 rows=179952 width=924) (actual time=3539.008..38743.818 rows=6 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_line_sort_index on line  (cost=0.56..2881081.84 rows=40287948 width=56) (actual time=0.107..14643.842 rows=10036002 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using lot_pkey on lot  (cost=0.43..0.55 rows=1 width=860) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=10036002)
               Index Cond: (id = line.lot_id)
               Filter: (discriminant_id = 2191)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 1.077 ms
 Execution Time: 38744.039 ms
(9 rows)
```

**Questions:**

**Question 1:** It seems that boosting the stats cannot solve the issue for every discriminant_value. But I don't understand why it did help the planer to choose the correct query plan in some cases, for some discriminant values. Can someone explain this behaviour?

**Question 2:** is there a way for me to make the planer not underestimate the discriminant filter? Is there a way to boost the usage of the `idx_lot_discriminant_id` instead of the `idx_line_sort_index` when it should?

**Question 3:** is my model scalable ?
My intuition tells me I did a bad move by splitting the model in two tables, and that I should denormalize the column discriminant_id in the table lines to create an index `(discriminant_id, sort_index)`. But I have more filters possibles in the `lot` table, so it means denormalize almost everything that is index in the `line` table...
The other thoughts I had:

- Using a CTE (or a subquery) to filter on the `lot` first, but since the filters are controlled by the user API, it's not efficient when the user is filtering by nothing. There is filters possible on the `line` table, which makes the pagination hard to do with the CTE.
- Using a materialized view: Since I want real time, I would use too much resource on refreshing the view.
- Switch my data store to something more appropriate to my usage (Cassandra?, Mongo?).

I'm a bit surprised Postgres cannot handle this use case, and I have the feeling that I am missing something important here.

**What are you thoughts?**